# SSIS delete files and folders based on different path strings

Tags: ssis

First question I've asked so bear with me!

We have a need to use an SSIS package to delete folders and files in various paths based on a list of location paths that is generated by an SQL query on one of our databases.

I have experimented with various structures but to no avail,
I'm new to SSIS so if this is a foolish question sorry!

Thanks for your time and patience

Answer (score 2):

You may use an `Execute SQL` task to execute your query and store the resultset in a variable of type `object`. Use this variable as a source for an ForEach container with `Foreach-ADO-Enumerator` as collection.

Comment: I have combined your suggestion with a File System task to delete directory contents. To feed the required paths in however I am currently using OLE DB Source feeding into a Cache Transformation feeding into a Recordset Destination. Mapping the record sheet to a variable and then using that to drive the foreach. Have not managed to do much testing yet however. What do you think of this? Is it right or will it end in tears?